# HTML FORM redirige a un archivo php erróneo

Tags: php, html, mail

Estoy haciendo un formulario en un sitio web para que los clientes se puedan subscribir a un newsletter.

Ya tengo listo el formulario y también una función que recopila los correos que se subscriben en un archivo txt (después me las ingenio para que se envie el newsletter). También, debo decir que tengo 2 formularios, uno para enviar correo a los dueños de la empresa y otro para subscribirse:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el código html es el siguiente:

```html
<th>
            <p style= "text-align: center; color: white;" >
                <!--CONTACTO CON GEMELOS-->
                        <form method="post" name="contact_form"
                            action="email.php" style="text-align: left; color: white;">
                            Your Name:
                            <br>
                                <input type="text" name="name" size="18">
                            <br>
                            Email Address:
                            <br>
                                <input type="text" name="email" size="18">
                            <br>
                            Message:
                            <br>
                                <textarea cols="20" rows="5" name="message"></textarea>
                            <br>
                                <input type="submit" value="Send">
                        <br>
            </p>
        </th>
        <th>
            <p style= "text-align: center; color: white;" >
                    <!--NEWSLETTER-->
                        <form method="post" name="sub_form"
                            action="testing_newsletter.php" style="text-align: left; color: white;">
                            SUBSCRIBE TO OUR NEWSLETTER !!!
                            <BR>
                            Your Name:
                            <br>
                                <input type="text" name="name" size="18">
                            <br>
                            Email Address:
                            <br>
                                <input type="text" name="email" size="18">
                            <br>
                                <input type="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE">
                            <br>

            </p>
        </th>
```

Como se puede ver, cada formulario dirige a un php distinto, uno siendo "email.php" (que en estos momentos no existe ya que estoy usando una versión de la página que cree para hacer pruebas) y otro siendo "test_newsletter.php". El problema viene cuando hago click en el buton "SUBSCRIBE", soy enviado a "email.php".  Curiosamente, al borrar la tabla de enviar un correo, soy enviado a "test_newsletter.php", pero la idea es que estén ambos formularios...¿alguien sabe como solucionar este problema?

No se si sirva, pero adjunto el php de "test_newsletter"

```php
<html>
<?php
    echo "PROBANDO PROBANDO";

        $file='correos.txt';
        $correo="/n". $_POST["email"] . "\n";
        $correo_env= $_POST["email"];
        file_put_contents ( $file , $correo, FILE_APPEND );

        mail($correo_env, "WELCOME!"  ,"Thank you for subscribing!");

?>
<br>
<a href="http://www.dualeffectgames.com/t3st1ngDu4lEff3cts/testing_index.html">go back</a>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que abrís las etiquetas de formulario  y no las estás cerrando, es por eso que cuando eliminaste el primer form te funciono correctamente.

Tenés que cerrar los formularios con la etiqueta `</form>`.